# In eclipse how to have a open url passed in

Tags: android, url, media-player

I am very new to programming but through determination have found a way to make an application that allows a media url to be played through my app the issue is im trying to make it so that its open to more that 1 specific url for that specific song Im trying to make it so that a playlist that is already set on a site can be chosen through this player if anyone is up to helping me learn and or taking the time to work with me through email or messaging please let me know the code i have so far for this app is as follows

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

String url = "http://beatswith.us/uploads/Mac%20Miller%20-%20Paper%20Route%20feat.%20Kev%20Da%20Hustla.mp3"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm reading your question right, it sounds like you currently have just one song your app will play but instead you want to be able to choose from a list of songs to play..

What you probably would want to do as a next step is create an array of songs and then use  ListView to allow the user to pick which song they want to play. It looks like this may be your first time programming. I suggest you look up some tuturials showing how a list view works and then make an ArrayAdapter to bind to your ListView.. The ArrayAdapter has an array (think of an array as being a variable that has more than 1 thing in it, in your case Strings which represent URL's to songs..

Here is some code to get you started:

```
 public class SongListActivity extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] songList = new String[] {  
       "http://beatswith.us/uploads/Mac%20Miller%20-%20Paper%20Route%20feat.%20Kev%20Da%20Hustla.mp3",
       "http://beatswith.us/another1.mp3",
       "http://beatswith.us/another2.mp3"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ArrayAdapter songAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songList);
     setListAdapter(songAdapter);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v,int pos, long id) {
      String url = (String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
      playSong(url);

    }


    private void playSong(String url) {
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      try {
         mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
         mediaPlayer.start();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } 
    }
}
```

here is more documentation that should help: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

You will need to update the array with valid URL's to songs.

-- Update --
I'm a bit confused still by the exact question.. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do.. If there is a playlist on a website (perhaps in xml format) you could download that xml file and then make a ListAdapter that you would use instead of an ArrayAdapter.. I mean really this gets much more complicated because in reality you probably want to show the name of the song so that means you need to parse the ID3 information from the mp3  -- which is relatively easy to do but it is definitely much more involved than what your current code does.. My example should give you a bit of an idea on how to play a list of songs and should get you a bit more programming experience before you move on to more complicated things.

Comment: Well i do appreciate it but I have already gotten familiar with a list view using whats already placed in there so instead of creating an array and listing each song in there i was wondering if its possible to get a call out to 1 single url and if i understand code correctly use something like a getSongId(); and have any song thats already posted in there playlist retrived. so maybe it would be something like this String url = getSongId()""; I dont really know how to code it but i hope you understand what i mean and yes i actually learned what i know from youtube so i am fresh to it all